# KeyError during Multithreading

Tags: python, multithreading, sockets, tcp, keyerror

I am currently programming a server that accepts multiple clients, creates a thread for each client and passes them all through a function `handle_client`. I am creating a list of every client that connects to the server and storing it in clients. I want to pass each client through a different `function block` and I am not sure how to achieve this with threading. So, for example here in my case the two clients are `Robot` and `Iconet`, I want to create a different function for each of the client and then I would wish to pass the client Robot through a `handle_robot` function designed for it and the client Iconet through a different `handle_iconet` which is designed for it. Here is the code of the server side. I am running into KeyError when using the method below to pass the target.

SERVER CODE

```
import threading 
import socket 

PORT = 1026
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER,PORT)
FORMAT = "utf-8"
HEADER = 1024

server = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server.bind(ADDR)
clients = []
aliases = ["Robot","Iconet"]

alias_dictionary_iter = zip(aliases,clients)
alias_dictionary = dict(alias_dictionary_iter)


def broadcast(values_iconet):
    for client in clients:
        client.send(values_iconet)
        
def handle_robot(client,addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    client.send('hello robot'.encode(FORMAT))

def handle_iconet(client,addr):
    print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
    client.send('hello iconet'.encode(FORMAT))

def start():
    server.listen()
    print(f"[LISTENING] Server is listening on {SERVER}")
    while True:
        client, addr = server.accept()
        clients.append(client)
        print(f"[NEW CONNECTION] {addr} connected.")
        client.send('Welcome'.encode(FORMAT))
        initial = client.recv(1024)
        print(initial)
        thread = threading.Thread(target= function_dictionary[client], args=(client,addr))
        thread.start()
       
functions = [handle_robot, handle_iconet]
function_dictionary_iter = zip(clients,functions)
function_dictionary = dict(function_dictionary_iter)

print ('[STARTING] server is starting')
start()
```

Here is the error message which i get when running the code:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Users\shoni\Documents\TcpCommExample\Server and clients\Untitled-1.py", line 66, in <module>
    start()
  File "c:\Users\shoni\Documents\TcpCommExample\Server and clients\Untitled-1.py", line 56, in start
    thread = threading.Thread(target= function_dictionary[client], args=(client,addr))
KeyError: <socket.socket fd=424, family=AddressFamily.AF_INET, type=SocketKind.SOCK_STREAM, proto=0, laddr=('10.14.0.2', 1026), raddr=('10.14.0.2', 53971)>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem doesn't appear to be related to the multithreading; rather it's in this line:

```
thread = threading.Thread(target= function_dictionary[client], args=(client,addr))
```

.... you are trying to look up a key `client` in `function_dictionary` that does not exist in `function_dictionary`, hence the `KeyError`.

The fix would be to either insert the new `client` key/value pair into the `function_dictionary` before trying to look it up there, or to not try to use `client` as a key into the dictionary.  (it's hard to say which, since it's not clear what the intent of `function_dictionary` is supposed to be)